# Create Kubernetes Pod with MySQL and PHP?

Tags: mysql, docker, kubernetes

Hi there,
I have a docker container that is a php backend. I have created a kubernetes pod of this container. This is what my yml file looks like:

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Pod
 metadata:
  name: backend
  spec:
  containers:
 - name: backend
  image: 000.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/fullstackapp
  ports:
  - containerPort: 8000
```

However I want to be able to connect my MySql database (which is also a docker container) to the backend in the same pod.  However I have no idea how to go about doing this.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Well,

Since you have dockerized your app (you made an docker image), you also must use a docker image for your MySql database.

But here is the kicker, you need also to create **services** for your app pod and your MySql pod.

You can find all the details in the k8 [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/) (which is really good)

To make myself clear:

1.) First create a [deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) object for your app.

2.) Then make a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) for your app.

You rinse and repeat for the MySql database.

1.) You need the **deployment** object (and not the pod kind), because the deployment object keeps you pod alive when one breaks, for instance if you have tree replicas (pods) the [replicaSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/) that the deployment object uses, will make sure that there are three replicas of your app.

2.) **Services** will group your pods (via **labels**), because the pods that the deployment object will generate will have a short life (**ephemeral**), meaning their IP address will be unstable and you wont be able to rely on them.

So, you will use services that will give you a cluster IP (**virtual IP**), that other objects can use. For instance; when your app wants to connect to the MySQL database.

You can use the **name** of the MySQL **service** in your apps configuration files.

So, basically that's how you would connect a **MySQL pod** to you **apps pod**.

Take a look at the [katacode](https://www.katacoda.com/) project, they give you a playground to learn this kind of stuff.

Tom